# table attributes are not correct with bootstrap

Tags: html, angular, bootstrap-4, angular-ui-tabset

I created a table using the bootstrap table , but the fields are not correct 
How can i fix them ? 
Only the first one is correct
[image]

Comment: Can you post your HTML. It's pretty hard to debug an image

Answer (score 0):

```html
"""<ngb-tab>
      <ng-template ngbTabTitle>
        <span jhiTranslate="mainPage.yearPlan">Jahresplanung</span>
      </ng-template>
      <ng-template ngbTabContent>
          <table class="table table-striped table-responsive" aria-hidden="true">
              <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="yearPlan">#</th>
                        <th class="yearPlan" jhiTranslate="yearPlan.april"></th>
                        <th class="yearPlan" jhiTranslate="yearPlan.mai"></th>
                        <th class="yearPlan" jhiTranslate="yearPlan.june"></th>
                        <th class="yearPlan" jhiTranslate="yearPlan.july"></th>
                        <th class="yearPlan" jhiTranslate="yearPlan.august"></th>
                        <th class="yearPlan" jhiTranslate="yearPlan.september"></th>
                        <th class="yearPlan" jhiTranslate="yearPlan.october"></th>
                        <th class="yearPlan" jhiTranslate="yearPlan.november"></th>
                        <th class="yearPlan" jhiTranslate="yearPlan.december"></th>
                        <th class="yearPlan" jhiTranslate="yearPlan.january"></th>
                        <th class="yearPlan" jhiTranslate="yearPlan.february"></th>
                        <th class="yearPlan" jhiTranslate="yearPlan.march"></th>
                        <th class="yearPlan" jhiTranslate="yearPlan.average"></th>
                    </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th class="yearPlan">AT</th>
                </tr>
                <br>
                <tr>
                          <th class="yearPlan">EPL Pakete pm</th>
                         ...
                          <th><p></p></th>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                            <th class="yearPlan">EPL DF</th>
                            ...
                            <th><p></p></th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>EPL Stopps pm</th>
                            ...
                            <th><p></p></th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>EPL Pakete pd</th>
                            <th><p></p></th>
                            ...
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>EPL Stopps pm</th>
                            <th><p></p></th>
                          ...
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>APL Pakete pm</th>
                            <th><input size="3"></th>
                            ...
                            <th><p></p></th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>APL KDF</th>
                            <th><input size="3"></th>
                            ...
                            <th><p></p></th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>APL Stopps pm</th>
                           ...
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>APL Pakete pd</th>
                            <th><p></p></th>
                            ...
                            <th><p></p></th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>APL Stopps pm</th>
                           ...
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Fahrzeuge</th>
                            ...
                            <th><input size="3"></th>
                            <th><p></p></th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>EPL Pakete pro FZG</th>
                            <th><p></p></th>
                            ...
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>EPL Stopps pro FZG</th>
                            <th><p></p></th>
                            <th><p></p></th>
                            ...
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>APL Pakete pro FZG</th>
                            <th><p></p></th>
                           ...
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>APL Stopps pro FZG</th>
                            <th><p></p></th>
                            <th><p></p></th>
                          ...
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                </table>
      </ng-template>
    </ngb-tab>
```